# Asynchronous method exec in PHP

Tags: php, multithreading, asynchronous

I need to start an asynchronous method call in PHP but have no idea or clue in how to achieve this. The big idea is as follow:

```
public myfunctionAction() {
    // normal flow
    // execute the asynchronous call (WS)
    // continue normal flow
}
```

How I do that? Can any provide a simple example just to use as a start point? It's possible to leave the asynchronous call executing on the background and continue the normal flow?

I'm using Symfony 2.6.x as development framework if that helps a little

Comment: do you want to execute an external program/script/ batch file ?

Comment: @HalayemAnis the idea is to start a remote WebService which will perform some calculations and insert back a value in the database, nothing else, in fact the normal flow just need to start the process in the other side but can continue without problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - You can use `curl` in php with a low time out
2 - You can use popen to start a batch or script shell without waiting the response : like `pclose(popen("ws_start.sh"));`

Hope that helps :)